# QPen in Orange?

Tags: c++, qt

When it's about to set a Qt Pen in blue, red or green, I can do the following:

```
QPen(Qt::blue));
QPen(Qt::red));
QPen(Qt::orange));
```

But when it's about to set an orange color, it's not recognized.

Then, how to set a QPen in orange?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at [QColor::setNamedColor()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qcolor.html#setNamedColor), it states:

`Sets the RGB value of this QColor to name, which may be in one of these formats: ... A name from the list of colors defined in the list of SVG color keyword names provided by the World Wide Web Consortium; for example, "steelblue" or "gainsboro"...`

And [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords) is the list of names you can use.

So you can do this:

```
QPen pen;
pen.setColor("orange");
```

Answer (score 6):

QColor understands SVG colors also (I find handy [this graphviz page](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/colors.html#svg) for reference).
Then you can just name it:

```
QColor c("orange")
```

The same page also reports actual values: orange is `#ffa500`

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of [predefined colors](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qt.html#GlobalColor-enum), or create a custom color, for example `QPen(QColor( 0xFF, 0xA0, 0x00 ))`

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the [Qt::GlobalCOlor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qt.html#id-47a5c1db-5617-403c-a62d-53006e4c019c) enum before trying that?
QT::orange does **not** exists!
As pointed out by  Dmitry, pass to `QPen` an instance of your custom `QColor` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize, a QPen Object with a QColor object, constructed using the RGB value for orange.

```
QColor orangeColor(255,165,0);
QPen(orangeColor);
```

Refer this [RGB](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aetf.html) chart for more colors.